# unable to set a session

Tags: android

I am very new in android.In my app I make a login page.I use Shared Preferences for session.it works fine but a problem when i close my app and again open then login page comes.I want when user press logout button only that time login page will come.

> this is my SharedPreferences class

```
public class SharedPrefManager {

//the constants
private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "dreamzsharedpref";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "keyusername";
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "keyphone";
private static final String KEY_ID = "keyid";

private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
private static Context mCtx;

private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
}

public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

//method to let the user login
//this method will store the user data in shared preferences
public void userLogin(User user) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(KEY_ID, user.getUserid());
    editor.putString(KEY_PHONE, user.getUserphno());
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, user.getUsername());
    editor.apply();
}

//this method will checker whether user is already logged in or not
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PHONE, null) != null;
}

//this method will give the logged in user
public User getUser() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return new User(
            sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null),
            sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_PHONE, null),
            sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_ID, -1)
    );
}


//this method will logout the user
public void logout() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
    mCtx.startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, LoginActivity.class));
}
}
```

> this is my login method in login class

```
private void userLogin() {

    //first getting the values
    final String username = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    final String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();

    //validating inputs
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
        UsernameEt.setError("Please enter your username");
        UsernameEt.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        PasswordEt.setError("Please enter your password");
        PasswordEt.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    //if everything is fine

    class UserLogin extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //creating request handler object
            RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

            //creating request parameters
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("vuserphno", username);
            params.put("votp", password);

            //returing the response
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_LOGIN, params);//this URLs is a class where URL_LOGIN is login url
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("user");

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    //getting the user from the response
                    JSONObject userJson = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    //creating a new user object
                    User user = new User(
                            userJson.getString("username"),
                            userJson.getString("userphno"),
                            userJson.getInt("userid")
                    );

                    //storing the user in shared preferences
                    SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);
                }

                    //starting the profile activity
                    finish();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
    ul.execute();
}
```

please tell me where is the problem and how I can solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: post the code of your launcher activity

Comment: login activity is launcher activity....when login button clicked called userLogin method.

Comment: You set `LoginActivity` as the launcher activity so it starts first, that's normal. But where in your code call `isLoggedIn` method and how do you handle when `isLoggedIn` returns `true`?

Comment: @TamHuynh yes...That is my question to how to handle isLoggedIn method?

Comment: @ArpanSarkar Check my answer

Comment: @TamHuynh I check your answer...and it worked for me..Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `LoginActivity`, check for login state and change activity, finish itself so it's clear from the back stack.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn(this)) {
        startActivity(this, MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // ...
}
```